# Phonegap application targeting android multiple screens?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, media-queries, android-screen-support

I'm trying to develop an android app with phonegap what is the best approach/method for targeting multiple screen sizes,

I tried the following methods:

- Viewport Metadata `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, user-scalable=no, target-densitydpi=device-dpi"/>`
- [Targeting Screens from Web Apps](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/targeting.html) - Android Docs
- `@media-queries`
- Multiple apks targeting different screen sizes - [Distributing to Specific Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution.html)

Is there any good examples or docs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can found countless example and articles on media queries on the internet..
You can mix media queries and maybe % based layout.